# Namespace Layout rendering with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an application with a namespace 'admin'.

I created my views on a folder called admin->highligths. And want that, when my views are rendered, it gets the layout from 'admin/layouts/application'.

But, when I render my pages, it is getting from the base layout folder.

```
  Rendered admin/highlights/index.html.erb within layouts/application (0.7ms)
```

My routes are like this:

namespace :admin do
    root 'pages#show', id: 'dashboard'

```
resources :events
resources :invitees do
  collection do
    get 'import_invitees/:year' => 'invitees#import_invitees', as: :import_invitees
  end
end
resources :highlights
resources :pages
resources :speakers
resources :sponsors
resources :users
resources :years do
  resources :events do
    resources :photos
  end
end
```

end

All my other views (sponsours, invitees, etc...) are getting the template from  'admin/layouts/application' , but highlight (the new one I created)only render with the 'layouts/application'.

What Im missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple possibilites.
In the dark, I would assume that your other Controllers inherit from an `AdminController` (or similar), that defines the layout, but the "new one" does not.

For reference about how to make controllers use certain layouts by defaults: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

Comment: Was exactly that Felix.